# ОС для ПК с ОЗУ 8 мегабайт

Tags: linux, ос

Имеется компьютер начала 90-х, который планируется использовать в качестве "микро"контролера хотелось бы иметь возможность писать скрипты на bash и пользоваться сетью. ОЗУ всего 8 мегабайт, загрузка возможна с hdd.

Comment: Кстати, если хочется потренироваться в понимании из чего устроено ядро, можно попробовать на одном из перечисленных ниже по ссылке дистрибутивов заменить ядро на какое-нибудь свежее LTS, например, v4.9.y. (При условии, что архитектура там не ниже i486+ или как её ещё называют i586tsc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Компьютер x86-совместимый?
Есть [подборка микро-дистров](http://www.linuxlinks.com/Distributions/Floppy/), многие из которых умещаются в 8Mb оперативной памяти, В частности Fd Linux на базе Red Hat (8Mb RAM) или PiTux (4Mb RAM).

Fd Linux — довольно специфичный дистр: сеть есть, bash есть, но поддержки дисков нет. В PiTux, как известно, нет ни дисков, ни сети из коробки.